# How to handle Error in Async Network programming?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, network-programming

I have the following method :

```
private void ClientReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                var networkStream = _client.GetStream();
                var read = networkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);

                if (read == 0)
                {
                    Disconnected?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
                }

                byte[] buffer = asyncResult.AsyncState as byte[];
                if (buffer != null)
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[read];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, read);
                    networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, ClientReadCallback, buffer);
                    DataRead?.Invoke(this, new DataReadEventArgs(data));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GetLog().Error(ex);
                ClientReadException?.Invoke(this, new ExceptionEventArgs(ex));
            }
        }
```

That triggers a  : System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object at some points.

My question is : in which situation does this happens? network issue? How to handle this properly ?
thanks

Comment: Your code accesses multiple objects that are IDisposable. So unless you carefully track their lifecycle, such exceptions are not strange at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate?Thx

Comment: read MSDN to learn what is IDisposable, and which classes implement it. That's something you must learn and embrace.